# Highly fluctuating value of test statistic in Anderson Darling test

Tags: python, goodness-of-fit, gamma-distribution, anderson-darling-test

I am trying to verify whether my sampled data is from a population with a Gamma density function. My plan is to do this by means of the Anderson-Darling test. Before doing so, I thought it would be good to see what would happen in the supervised case, that is, if I generate data according to a Gamma($\alpha, \beta$) after which I apply the AD test to it. I am using the AD test statistic
$$
A^2_n = -\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{2i-1}{n}\Big\{ln[F(x_{(i)})] + ln[1-F(x_{(n+1-i)})] \Big\}-n
$$

I implemented this in Python, yielding the following code

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
from math import log

shape = 19.28  # ground truth shape parameter
scale = 0.62111  # ground truth scale parameter 
n = 10000  # number of samples

rv = ss.gamma(a=shape, loc=0, scale=scale)  # fix the gamma distribution with specified parameters
x = np.sort(rv.rvs(size=n))  # create n samples, sorted ascending

# Anderson Darling test statistic
x = np.append(0, x)  # add element to correct for 0-basedness of Python
ad = -1 * n - sum([((2 * i - 1) / n) * (log(rv.cdf(x[i])) + log(1 - rv.cdf(x[n + 1 - i]))) for i in range(1, n + 1)])

print(ad)
```

Now what stands out to me, is that when I perform this with a relatively large sample size of $n = 10000$, the value of $A^2_n$ fluctuates enormously: sometimes it returns a value close to 2.00, sometimes close to 0.40. This seems strange to me, as in **both** cases the specified density seems a very good fit to the histogram of the sampled data.

**Question:**

How is it possible that the value of $A^2_n$ fluctuates that much, even if I use a large sample size? Does this follow from statistical theory or may it be that my implementation is wrong?

Comment: The amount of fluctuation of $A_n^2$ is irrelevant.  If you don't like it, you are free to (say) divide $A_n^2$ by $n.$  You would have to adjust the critical value accordingly, but the test results would remain the same.

Comment: Yes, but how is it possible that, for a fixed $n$ (being large), the value of $A^2_n$ sometimes is close to 2.0 and another time (after I took a new sample) close to, say, 0.3? I would expect this to happen if I have a relatively small sample size because of the randomness, but not as n is e.g. 10000. Is this a false expectation from my side? Note that in both cases, the Gamma density seems a good fit to the sample based on a histogram comparison.

Comment: It's a false expectation--but your question is *why* is that so?  One (somewhat glib) answer is that it's designed that way: the formula for $A_n^2$ is adjusted so that the distribution will tend to have nearly a unit variance for any $n.$  (In fact, as $n$ grows large the distribution of $\log A_n^2$ becomes very nearly Normal and hardly varies with $N.$)  More to the point, under the null hypothesis any useful statistic is going to vary. The right question to ask is *how does the entire distribution of $A_n^2$ change as a function of how much the distribution departs from the null?*

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your reply. This is a clear answer. One additional remark, however, from my side is that it feels quite counter-intuitive that this implies that if I take two exclusive samples from a Gamma distr. with $n$ very large, the AD test for testing whether they are from a Gamma distr. sometimes results in a acceptance of the null and sometimes easily rejects it. I'd thought that this would not be the case for large values of $n$.

Comment: Hypothesis tests at a level $\alpha$ are *constructed* so that when the null is true, the test statistic will be significant $100\alpha\%$ of the time.  This is designed to hold no matter how large $n$ might be.  In other words, this behavior is built right into the testing framework.  It's not special to the AD test.